# Using UnityEngine.Animations.Rigging; not found

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, package, using-directives

My Unity project has the Animation Rigging Package. As we all know if we write a script where we need to reference some kind of Rig we must use the namespace/using direction for this package. Here is my question. What if I need to reference a Rig in another namespace? The script is now unable to find the using direction for it? Any solutions or ideas on this?

Thanks for your input.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Timers;
using OutrunUndeath.Scripts.Characters.Player.Bombs;
using OutrunUndeath.Scripts.Constants;
using OutrunUndeath.Scripts.Handlers.Characters;
using OutrunUndeath.Scripts.Handlers.DamageHandlers;
using OutrunUndeath.Scripts.Managers;
using OutrunUndeath.Scripts.Obstacles;
using OutrunUndeath.Scripts.UiPanles.GamePanels.PlayerHud;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.Animations.Rigging; // not found

namespace OutrunUndeath.Scripts.Characters.Player {
```

Comment: Are you sure you have imported `Animation Rigging` package in your project?

Comment: Yeah sure. Otherwise, I couldn't set up Rigs/Multi Aim Constraints and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As always in programming, it was human failure. I forgot to assign the animation Rigging Utils to the right Assembly Definition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try using "using UnityEditor.Animations.Rigging;"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the Input. But it doesn't work.